# WebApi - Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found)

Tags: c#, json, rest, asp.net-web-api2, bson

I am trying to send image and its metadata (like name) via `Newtonsoft.Json.Bson` to a WebApi Restful Server from C# console client.

**Client Code:**

```
    public async Task SendRequestAsync(byte[] imageBytes, string fileName)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        using (var bson = new Newtonsoft.Json.Bson.BsonWriter(stream))
        {
            var jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer();

            var json = JObject.FromObject(new
            {
                name = fileName,
                content = imageBytes
            });

            jsonSerializer.Serialize(bson, json);

            var client = new HttpClient
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:1920")
            };

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                    new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/bson"));

            var byteArrayContent = new ByteArrayContent(stream.ToArray());
            byteArrayContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/bson");

            var result = await client.PostAsync(
                    "api/Files", byteArrayContent);
            try
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                Console.Out.WriteLine(response.IsSuccessStatusCode);
                Console.Out.WriteLine(response.Headers);
                Console.Out.WriteLine(response.Content);
                Console.Out.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Server Code**

```
// WebApi Controller
    public JsonResult<object> Post([FromBody]FileModel fileModel)
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine(fileModel.name);
        Console.Out.WriteLine(fileModel.length);

        return Json<object>(new
        {
            status = HttpStatusCode.OK,
            length = fileModel.length,
            name = fileModel.name
        });
    }

// Model Class
    public class FileModel
    { 
        public string name { get; set; }
        public byte[] content { get; set; }
        public int length { get; set; }
    }
```

If I send an image of 28KB then server receive the image successfully. But If I try to send image of 20MB then I get following error

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).
   at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
   at FileUploadConsole.Program.<SendRequestAsync>d__1.MoveNext() in c:\users\Projects\FileUploadConsole\FileUploadConsole\Program.cs:line 58
```

Line 58 is `HttpResponseMessage response = result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();`

Why for large image its not able to find the service ?

Comment: It may depend on web-server configuration. Max request size I mean.

Comment: In the server side I set the `maxRequestLength` to > 145MB - `<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" maxRequestLength="150536"/>`, but error remains same. I tried to upload 27MB image.

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295" /> 
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
```

The `maxAllowedContentLength` specifies maximums content length in bytes and is represented by a uint, see [reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms689462%28VS.90%29.aspx).
The value in my example is set to the [greatest possible uint value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/uint) (4 gb).